# How to host binaries in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm trying to find a way to host source binaries in Azure Dev Ops that are zip assemblies, not nugets.

I have a repo that hosts PowerShell scripts that are used to install an external solution. The external solution comes as zipped binaries that are manually downloaded.
I need to create a pipeline to distribute this installer package (scripts + source binaries)
I do not want to host the zip binaries in my repos as the files are pretty big.
The ideal would be to have only the scripts in git and when running the pipeline, to go get the latest zip binaries and package them with the scripts.

I tried to publish the `sourceBinaries.zip` to my artifact feed, but it is not a nuget and it doesn't work.

Thank you for your suggestions

**Note and Final Solution**

Something I forgot to mention is that we use Azure DevOps "On Premise" (whatever the name is).
Using Universal Packages have been suggested but the "On Premise" version doesn't have this option. It would have been the perfect though!

What I end up doing is packaging the binaries in nuget packages. Publish it on the project's Artifact feed and then add special tasks to unpack it all in my pipeline. Nuget are some type of archive file with metadata so it works pretty good. It's just added labor to pack...

Comment: You can use Universal Packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the files are less than 2 GiB, you can use the Universal Packages as mentioned in the comment by Daniel Mann. Azure Artifacts is free for every organization up to 2 GiB of storage. See [Publish and download Universal Packages with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for detailed steps.
2. If the files are more than 2 GiB, you can consider [using Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=azure-devops#use-git-large-file-storage-lfs). Git LFS is fully supported and free in Azure DevOps Services. Just follow [the instructions to install the client](https://git-lfs.github.com/), set up LFS tracking for files on your local repo, and then push your changes to Azure Repos.
3. You can also use another repo to store the files and check out multiple repositories in your pipeline. See [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-resource-definition).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately, Universal Packages aren't an option with "On Premise" Azure Dev Ops. The other options may be possible although I'm not sure LFS in available with "On Premise". we need to move out of "On Premise" :( ...